# How to get the Android Memory Monitor values (Allocated and Free) programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, memory-management, android-sdk-2.3

I'm familiar with [Debug.MemoryInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.MemoryInfo.html) but non of these values give me the allocated memory that is shown in the Memory Monitor graph.

1. What exactly is this allocated memory value and why it's different from the values discussed in [Debug.MemoryInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.MemoryInfo.html)?
2. How can I get the allocated memory value of a procces through its PID programmatically?

Comment: [This link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html?utm_source=android-studio#vm) might be useful

Comment: I couldn't find there any information regarding how to collect this info programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()



    Log.e( "totalMemory ", String.valueOf(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()));
    Log.e( "freeMemory : ", String.valueOf(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()));
    Log.e( "maxMemory: ", String.valueOf(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()));
```

Comment: How can I use it to find out memory details of **other** apps and not mine? (app that check memory of other apps)